# Arabic enumerating inside an alpha enumerating

Tags: enumitem

I'm wondering how to show the original enumerating instead of `alpha` inside the list. `enumitem` package is included.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
      \item The first item
      \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
        \item Nested item 1
        \item Nested item 2
      \end{enumerate}
      \item The second item
      \item The third etc \ldots
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

What the code gives:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just omit the `*` after `label` in the inner enumerate. The star appends the labelling of the outer ('parent') list to the inner list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
        \item The first item
            \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.}]
                \item Nested item 1
                \item Nested item 2
            \end{enumerate}
        \item The second item
        \item The third etc \ldots
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is `*` doing after `\alph` and `\arabic`?

Comment: @FiboKowalsky: Reading the manual helps: It is an internal format for `enumerate` labels, in order to prevent the code using `\alph` and `\arabic` directly.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `*` from the `label=` in the nested list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
      \item The first item
      \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
        \item Nested item 1
        \item Nested item 2
      \end{enumerate}
      \item The second item
      \item The third etc \ldots
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Gives you the list you want:

[image: List]

Comment: Yes, it seems as if you were a little bit faster than me with writing your answer. When submitting mine, I didn't see there is another one. I'm new to stackexchange - how do you usually handle those "duplicate replys"? Shall I remove mine? Or just leave it there?

Comment: Apparently you're German: Wo kein Richter da kein Henker ;-) Willkommen bei TeX.SX  -- der Guten Seite der Typographie ;-)

Comment: `label={}`, i.e. curly brackets may be required